# Passing arguments with a link in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a schedule/calendar app that I wrote in Rails that I'm rewriting using Backbone (and Rails, still).

In the old app, when you would click a time slot to make a new appointment, it would pass the date and time in the query string.

For Backbone, maybe I want to do the same thing. I'm apprehensive, though, because 1) I don't know how to read the query string with Backbone (which isn't a big deal - I can figure that out) and, more importantly, 2) maybe Backbone offers a way to pass this data that's better than what I was doing before.

So my question is: **should I pass the date/time data in the query string or does Backbone have a better way that I haven't thought of**? The query string solution has always felt a little clunky, so I thought I'd check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone implements a REST API out of the box, which you should try to follow as much as possible.

```
url              HTTP Method    Operation
/api/books       GET            Get an array of all books
/api/books/:id   GET            Get the book with id of :id
/api/books       POST           Add a new book and return the book with an id attribute added
/api/books/:id   PUT            Update the book with id of :id
/api/books/:id   DELETE         Delete the book with id of :id
```

For the purpose of creating a new Appointment.  You'd basically make a new instance of AppointmentModel, which extends Backbone.Model.  Define the URL as "/api/appointments" or something similar.

Calling appointmentModel1.save() will issue a POST to /api/appointments containing all the data in the model.

Don't use QueryStrings - or you'll end up overriding the backbone URLs EVERYWHERE and will loose a lot of functionality that backbone can take care of for you.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally knew about the routing stuff but I guess I kind of forgot. Thanks.

Comment: @reach4thelasers Using this approach, how would you GET a list of books within a range? Say books with a title A - C.